# How to make ticks cross axis domain in Python Altair

Tags: python, altair

I can't find a way to make the ticks cross the axis domain baseline in using altair. What I want is this (chart made with a different graphing tool):
[cross_ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eguGr.png)

but all I can get is this (chart made with altair):
[no_cross_ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXnn1.png)

Referencing the [altair.Axis documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.Axis.html), I tried using the tickCap, tickOffset, and tickSize parameters to change it, but they wouldn't give me what I want.

Here is the code to generate the altair example:

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0, 1, 2], "y": [0, 1, 2]})

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x="x",
    y="y",
).configure_axis(
    grid=False,
)

chart.save("no_cross.png")
```

Comment: Clarification: I want to change the style of the tick marks on the axis lines. Right now the tick marks only extend off of one side of the axis line, like an uppercase T. I want them to extend off of both sides, like a plus sign +.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unfortunately. You could create small lines with mark_rule instead as a somewhat tedious workaround